# Install 14.04 seems frozen at any questions screen

Tags: system-installation, system

Installing ubuntu 14.04 seems frozen at the "any questions?"logo. The little circle thing is still going around, but I can't tell if it is doing anything. Does it take a long time to erase the old stuff on the hd while installing new os?

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing LVM and encrypting the disk it will take a good long while. Especially, if you have a large disk.